# A way to send email based on cell value changed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to figure out the how to make a Google Sheets send emails to a user (similar to [labnol Amazon Price Tracker](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aofk8L6brI_edEN0UmpaUVZaTGZZOXdPQXdJdFV5ZWc&newcopy=true)). So far I have created a coupon tracker sheet using:

```
=importxml(A1,"//span[@class='myclass']") //just a demo
```

**What I want to do:**

→ User should add email in a cell and that cell activate/authorize (similar to labnol) 
→ Send email when the value of cell changes (like B3 value change)
→ User should be able to start/stop the tracker
→ A way to hide the code (the script/formula used)

Answer (score 0):

In the **Tools** menu, choose **Script Editor** and create an `onEdit()` function:

[Google Documentation - onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/index#onedit)

```
function onEdit() {
  Logger.log('onEdit ran!');
}
```

If the edit is from a single cell, you can get the cell value with this code:

[Google Documentation - Event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

```
function onEdit(e) {
  Logger.log('e.value: ' + e.value);
}
```

In the menu, VIEW the LOGS, and see what value was returned.

Then expand your code some more:

If the value is correct, send the email:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  Logger.log('e.value: ' + e.value);

  if (e.value === "correcValue") {
    // The code below will send an email with the current date an time
    var now = new Date();
    GmailApp.sendEmail("theEmailAddressHere@gmail.com", "current time", "The time is: " + now.toString());
  };
}
```

You need to work out the details yourself.  If you have a specific problem, post your code with the line of code that is the problem, and the error message that you are getting.